# this.getClass().getFields().length; always returns 0

Tags: java, reflection, count, field

I am trying to get the number of fields in a particular class.  However the technique I am using is not working and always returns 0:

```
this.getClass().getFields().length;
```

How do I get the field count of a particular class?

Comment: `getFields()` only returns `public` fields.

Comment: I realize now that this is a duplicate, but I did spend more than 20 minutes searching and really did not find any question that answered my question.  Perhaps the search engine needs to be improved a little.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use `this.getClass().getDeclaredFields().length`
The `getFields` method is for accessible public fields - see [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

Comment: I see. This is where I get a little confused.  I thought since the getters/setters where public they would be included.  My mistake.  Thanks.

Comment: Getters and setters are _not_ treated specially in any way, generally speaking.

Comment: Honestly, this tricks me every time I use reflection.

Comment: If you want, there is another trick. You can make setAccessible( true ); and dynamically when the program is running, those fields will be accessible.

Answer (score 2):

From the [`Class#getFields`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getFields%28%29) JavaDoc:

> Returns an array containing Field objects reflecting **all the accessible public fields of the class or interface** represented by this Class object.

Maybe your fields are declared as `private` or `protected`, thus never getting the right number of fields in your class. You should use [`Class#getDeclaredFields`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29)

> Returns an array of Field objects reflecting all the fields declared by the class or interface represented by this Class object. This includes **public, protected, default (package) access, and private fields**, but excludes inherited fields.

Answer (score 2):

`getFields()` only returns publicly accessible fields. Chances are, your class' fields are wrapped by getters and setters.

You would want to use `getDeclaredFields()` instead. It will return all fields, regardless of visibility.